# How to destroy resources from particular workspace in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-workspace

I have created resources in a different workspace in Terraform but I am not able to destroy resource from one specific workspace. Is there any way to destroy resources by specifying the workspace?

I have tried switched to that specific workspace while destroying resources but it is still pointing to other workspace's state file.

I am using the below commands:

```
Terraform workspace new test
Terraform apply -var-file terraform.test.tfvars 
Terraform destroy
```

Comment: How is your workspace configured and which commands have you run?

Comment: I have added commands in to issue description

Answer (score -1):

You have to first select the workspace with the following command

```
terraform workspace select <workspace_name>
```

Then you can destroy the workspace with

```
terraform destroy -refresh=false
```

if you want to list the workspaces created use

```
terraform workspace list
```

Comment: I am facing same problem and this destroy command is not working

Comment: This is not working,..

Comment: you have to make sure you are in directory where you applied the terraform template